# forUnifiedNativeAd is depricated | AdMob | Android

Tags: android, kotlin, admob

In given below sample of AdLoader builder, forUnifiedNativeAd is deprecated in admob. Check the code below.

```
  val adLoader = AdLoader.Builder(this, AdsConstant.ADS_NATIVE)
        .forUnifiedNativeAd(binding.nativeAd::setNativeAd)
        .withAdListener(object : AdListener() {
            override fun onAdFailedToLoad(adError: LoadAdError) {
                print(adError)
            }
        })
        .build()
```

Comment: You can use *forNativeAd* instead

Comment: @behrooz "forUnifiedNativeAd" is the one which is depricated bro

Comment: sorry i forgot to remove Unified :) i edited my comment you can use *forNativeAd*

Comment: And you must edit your layouts too